# Application hangs when stopping embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I am developing a Java based application including an embedded Tomcat. The startup of Tomcat works just fine like that:

```
logger.info("Starting application server");

    String baseDir = ConfigHandler.getProperty("tomcat.baseDir");
    tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.enableNaming();
    tomcat.setPort(ConfigHandler.getIntegerProperty("tomcat.defaultPort", 8080));
    tomcat.setBaseDir(baseDir);

    tomcat.getHost().setAppBase(baseDir);
    tomcat.getHost().setAutoDeploy(true);

    try
    {
        webContext = tomcat.addWebapp(tomcat.getHost(), "/orion", Files.createTempDirectory("orion_doc_base").toString());
        webContext.setAltDDName("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml");
        //URL url = (new File("src/main/resources/META-INF/context.xml")).toURI().toURL();
        //webContext.setConfigFile(url);
        tomcat.getServer().setShutdown("SHUTDOWN");
        tomcat.start();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.fatal("Error starting server!", e);

    }
    catch(LifecycleException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Error starting server!", e);
    }

    logger.info("Application server ready with Tomcat listening on port " + String.valueOf(ConfigHandler.getIntegerProperty("tomcat.defaultPort", 8080)));
    tomcat.getServer().await();
```

However, when I try to shutdown Tomcat, the whole application hangs and the shutdown is incomplete:

```
try
    {
        logger.warn("Shutting down tomcat...");
        webContext.stop();
        System.out.println("ORIONStarter.shutdown - 1");
        tomcat.stop();
        System.out.println("ORIONStarter.shutdown - 2");

        logger.warn("Tomcat has been shut down");
    }
    catch(LifecycleException e)
    {
        logger.throwing(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The console output is as follows:

```
05.10.2018 19:33:53.143+0200 [WARN] de.blackhole.software.orion.base.boot.ORIONStarter - Shutting down tomcat...
ORIONStarter.shutdown - 1
ORIONStarter.shutdown - 2
```

My tomcat version is

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.14</version>
    </dependency>
```

**UPDATE**

Here's the thread dump when the application hangs:

```
    2018-10-06 10:35:27
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (10.0.1+10 mixed mode):

Threads class SMR info:
_java_thread_list=0x00007f8847d0f2d0, length=17, elements={
0x00007f88480f4800, 0x00007f88480ec000, 0x00007f884901c800, 0x00007f8849028000,
0x00007f8849029000, 0x00007f88480ef000, 0x00007f884902a000, 0x00007f8848802800,
0x00007f88481f5000, 0x00007f88480d7800, 0x00007f8849d54000, 0x00007f884af08000,
0x00007f884d03a000, 0x00007f884b9e1000, 0x00007f884b98a000, 0x00007f884b98d000,
0x00007f884baf4800
}

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f88480f4800 nid=0x4503 waiting on condition  [0x0000700005c0b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.waitForReferencePendingList(java.base@10.0.1/Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.processPendingReferences(java.base@10.0.1/Reference.java:174)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.access$000(java.base@10.0.1/Reference.java:44)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(java.base@10.0.1/Reference.java:138)

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f88480ec000 nid=0x3a03 in Object.wait()  [0x0000700005d0e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@10.0.1/Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000006c026fb18> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@10.0.1/ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    - waiting to re-lock in wait() <0x00000006c026fb18> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@10.0.1/ReferenceQueue.java:172)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(java.base@10.0.1/Finalizer.java:216)

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f884901c800 nid=0x5803 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8849028000 nid=0xa703 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   No compile task

"C2 CompilerThread1" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8849029000 nid=0xa603 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   No compile task

"C1 CompilerThread2" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f88480ef000 nid=0x5d03 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   No compile task

"Sweeper thread" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f884902a000 nid=0xa303 runnable  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Common-Cleaner" #9 daemon prio=8 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8848802800 nid=0xa003 in Object.wait()  [0x0000700006320000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@10.0.1/Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000006c02708c8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@10.0.1/ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    - waiting to re-lock in wait() <0x00000006c02708c8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at jdk.internal.ref.CleanerImpl.run(java.base@10.0.1/CleanerImpl.java:148)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@10.0.1/Thread.java:844)
    at jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.run(java.base@10.0.1/InnocuousThread.java:134)

"Monitor Ctrl-Break" #10 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f88481f5000 nid=0x6103 runnable  [0x0000700006423000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.base@10.0.1/Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(java.base@10.0.1/SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(java.base@10.0.1/SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(java.base@10.0.1/SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(java.base@10.0.1/StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(java.base@10.0.1/StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(java.base@10.0.1/StreamDecoder.java:178)
    - locked <0x00000006c0272e18> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(java.base@10.0.1/InputStreamReader.java:185)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(java.base@10.0.1/BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(java.base@10.0.1/BufferedReader.java:326)
    - locked <0x00000006c0272e18> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(java.base@10.0.1/BufferedReader.java:392)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2$1.run(AppMainV2.java:64)

"Service Thread" #11 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f88480d7800 nid=0x6303 runnable  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"process reaper" #14 daemon prio=10 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8849d54000 nid=0x6403 waiting on condition  [0x0000700006650000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@10.0.1/Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c055d560> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.base@10.0.1/LockSupport.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(java.base@10.0.1/SynchronousQueue.java:462)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(java.base@10.0.1/SynchronousQueue.java:361)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(java.base@10.0.1/SynchronousQueue.java:937)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(java.base@10.0.1/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1060)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@10.0.1/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1121)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@10.0.1/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@10.0.1/Thread.java:844)

"NioBlockingSelector.BlockPoller-1" #53 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f884af08000 nid=0x14203 runnable  [0x0000700008cc2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(java.base@10.0.1/Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(java.base@10.0.1/KQueueArrayWrapper.java:196)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(java.base@10.0.1/KQueueSelectorImpl.java:116)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(java.base@10.0.1/SelectorImpl.java:89)
    - locked <0x00000006c14112f0> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x00000006c1411300> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x00000006c14112a0> (a sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(java.base@10.0.1/SelectorImpl.java:100)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector$BlockPoller.run(NioBlockingSelector.java:339)

"Tomcat-startStop-1" #54 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f884d03a000 nid=0xd403 waiting on condition  [0x0000700008dc5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@10.0.1/Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c16e81c8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.base@10.0.1/LockSupport.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(java.base@10.0.1/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2117)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(java.base@10.0.1/LinkedBlockingQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(java.base@10.0.1/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1060)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@10.0.1/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1121)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@10.0.1/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@10.0.1/Thread.java:844)

"localhost-startStop-1" #55 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f884b9e1000 nid=0x13f03 waiting on condition  [0x0000700008ec8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@10.0.1/Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c1a76e48> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.base@10.0.1/LockSupport.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(java.base@10.0.1/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2117)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(java.base@10.0.1/LinkedBlockingQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(java.base@10.0.1/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1060)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@10.0.1/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1121)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@10.0.1/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@10.0.1/Thread.java:844)

"SIGINT handler" #95 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f884b98a000 nid=0x15d03 in Object.wait()  [0x000070000b740000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@10.0.1/Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000006c155f580> (a de.blackhole.software.orion.base.Main$1)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(java.base@10.0.1/Thread.java:1353)
    - waiting to re-lock in wait() <0x00000006c155f580> (a de.blackhole.software.orion.base.Main$1)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(java.base@10.0.1/Thread.java:1427)
    at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.runHooks(java.base@10.0.1/ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:107)
    at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks$1.run(java.base@10.0.1/ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:46)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.runHooks(java.base@10.0.1/Shutdown.java:123)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.sequence(java.base@10.0.1/Shutdown.java:167)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.exit(java.base@10.0.1/Shutdown.java:212)
    - locked <0x00000006c028ab88> (a java.lang.Class for java.lang.Shutdown)
    at java.lang.Terminator$1.handle(java.base@10.0.1/Terminator.java:51)
    at jdk.internal.misc.Signal$1.run(java.base@10.0.1/Signal.java:220)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@10.0.1/Thread.java:844)

"Thread-1" #51 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f884b98d000 nid=0x1fa03 waiting for monitor entry  [0x000070000b843000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.exit(java.base@10.0.1/Shutdown.java:212)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000006c028ab88> (a java.lang.Class for java.lang.Shutdown)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exit(java.base@10.0.1/Runtime.java:118)
    at de.blackhole.software.orion.base.boot.ORIONStarter.shutdown(ORIONStarter.java:155)
    at de.blackhole.software.orion.base.Main$1.run(Main.java:64)

"DestroyJavaVM" #98 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f884baf4800 nid=0x2603 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"VM Thread" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f88480da800 nid=0x4603 runnable  

"GC Thread#0" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f884801d000 nid=0x2b03 runnable  

"GC Thread#1" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f884880a000 nid=0x5103 runnable  

"GC Thread#2" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f884801d800 nid=0x4f03 runnable  

"GC Thread#3" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f884801e800 nid=0x4d03 runnable  

"G1 Main Marker" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f884804b800 nid=0x2c03 runnable  

"G1 Conc#0" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f884804c000 nid=0x4b03 runnable  

"G1 Refine#0" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f88480cd000 nid=0x4a03 runnable  

"G1 Refine#1" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f88480cd800 nid=0x3203 runnable  

"G1 Refine#2" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8849800800 nid=0x3403 runnable  

"G1 Refine#3" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f88480ce800 nid=0x4803 runnable  

"G1 Young RemSet Sampling" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f88480cf000 nid=0x3503 runnable  
"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f884884e000 nid=0x9d03 waiting on condition  

JNI global references: 20

Heap
 garbage-first heap   total 378880K, used 117760K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 1024K, 89 young (91136K), 7 survivors (7168K)
 Metaspace       used 61192K, capacity 62505K, committed 62812K, reserved 1105920K
  class space    used 6738K, capacity 7187K, committed 7292K, reserved 1048576K


Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not having any incomplete threads that are holding tomcat from stopping?

Comment: shutdown of tomcat is incomplete or shutdown of the application?
because the application is not shutdown, for that you should use `System.exit(0)`

Comment: @Gewure: The application does not shut down because tomcat hangs during shutdown.

Comment: I wouldn't know how there are incomplete threads, because during testing I try to shutdown right after starting it.

Comment: @Abenstex then i think this might be your problem: `tomcat.getServer().await();` .. does the wrapping method throw an exception? also.. did you try debugging?

Comment: When it is "hung" initiate a thread dump and edit your question to include the thread dump.